# Is there an option in PostgreSQL to update a column value automatically on insert in another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one problem. I wanted to do it on a database level if it's possible.

So I have first table:

**Nutrition Table**

```
id PK
CaloriesSummary
CarbsSummary
FatSummary
.
.
.
```

The other table is **Meals**, where each meal contains a value for nutrients.

**Meals table**

```
id 
ForNutrition - foreign key for nutrition table
Calories
Carbs
Fat
.
.
.
```

What I want to do is, whenever a meal is added or updated or deleted, to change a summary inside of a Nutrition table. I know how to do it through the API, but I wanted to see if there is a way to do this on a DB level.

Comment: I don't fully understand your data model, but could nutrition just be a view that summarizes data from meals?

Comment: So whenever the endpoint for example /addMeal or /updateMeal is hit, the meal should update the nutrition table by the foreign key. 
And depending on endpoint, to add, substract or change a value of a Summary column inside the Nutrition table. 

I'm not sure if you understand. 
I thought of triggers but i don't know would it be a good idea.

Comment: @Jeremy So when a meal is added, a view should summarize the values for that Nutrition Id, and update the values? Ok sounds nice. I'll try it!

Comment: A view would not update the values, it's basically just a stored query which, in your case, could be used to summarize data.